# Grant User Credential Permission to an app programmatically via another Device Owner App

Tags: android, security, android-permissions, credentials, device-owner

One of my apps requires the use of a User Credential, already installed into the android store.

If I try to access the certificates via using the KeyChain class, I obtain an exception:

> android.security.KeyChainException:IllegalStateException: uid doesn't
>   have permission to access the requested alias

I want to avoid the user from having to manually "select" the user credential prompt.

Instead, I have a separate app, already set as a "device owner" to configure all of this.

Is there some API using the device owner app, where I can grant permission to the app trying to access the installed user credential?